# How to handle fetch URLs with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I am trying to deploy my nextjs app to vercel, however it keeps failing at the index fetch URL portion of the code.  In my `index.js` file of the pages dir I have the following code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.ROOT}/api/users`)
  const users = await res.json()
  return {props: {users: users.users}}
}

export default Index;
```

which is pulling the relative URL form the `next.config.js` like so:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    ROOT: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `https://vercel.com/myaccount/myappname` : `http://localhost:3000`
  }
};
```

The keeps failing at `FetchError: invalid json response body at https://vercel.com/myaccount/myappname`

Is there a better way to do this, or figure out what URL I should specify for production? It works fine in development

Comment: I have and in development at least I get the following error: ```TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported```

Comment: Ah sorry I made a mistake. getStaticProps is for fetching data at build time: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation,
So, assuming the url is the url of the nextjs website, it should not work as the website has not been built yet. Instead of api / getStaticProps, maybe you meant to use getServerSideProps instead to do server side rendering? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops

Comment: ```export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`/api/users`)
  const users = await res.json()
  return {props: {users: users.users}}
}``` Still getting that same error. I'll dig through the docs to see if there's something else I should be doing. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You dont have to perform a fetch there, just use the code defined in your api/user directly in getServerSideProps  to get the data needed at run time. Use fetch only if you are fetching from an external url, and in that case use getStaticProps for data that only changes at build time, or getServerSideProps for data that needs to be refetched on each page generation

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. This method seems a lot more useful for populating data than using fetch requests in ```getStaticProps``` - is there any benefit to using ```getStaticProps``` over just querying the database directly from ```getServerSideProps```?

Comment: You can do the same for either `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`, it depends on your use case and the nature of the data, please see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, you are trying to do retrieve data from your `api` route before it has been build, as `getStaticProps` is used at build time, hence the error. In any case you should not be fetching data from your own api routes in `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`, instead, reuse the code in your `api` route to retrieve data directly in `getStaticProps` (for build time) or  `getServerSideProps` (for server side generated). Another way is to use client side data fetching instead (see below).

To add on to the discussion, there are a few ways you can populate your components data in Next.js:

`getStaticProps`:

This is where you can fetch data at build time e.g. using `fetch` or reading files, and this is usually used for data that is largely unchanging, e.g. blog posts, articles. If your site is made entirely of static pages, you can export them as static files (HTML and JSON) and cache them on CDNs for improved performance, which is what Vercel does automatically for you.

`getServerSideProps`:

This is for server side rending and fetching data at each page request. This may be used if you need to serve unique data on every request, e.g. displaying user-specific data. In Vercel each request would be served by serverless functions, and you can cache them at the CDN manually with the `Cache-Control` header: https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/caching

Client side data fetch:

You can use ajax calls client side as well, e.g. using `fetch` within your component, usually when you need to have more dynamic user interactions. In this case it may be helpful to define some `/api` routes which your client can consume.

Vercel recommends going with `getStaticProps` and client side data fetching for performance reasons, and this may be a useful guide: https://vercel.com/blog/nextjs-server-side-rendering-vs-static-generation, but there may be certain use cases where server side rendering is necessary, e.g. if you want your site to work without javascript enabled.

Further Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching