# "FetchError: invalid json response body" while deploying to Vercel

Tags: typescript, deployment, next.js, fetch-api, vercel

I'm new to TypeScript, Next.js and Vercel, and having an issue in deploying my code onto Vercel. Kindly help me, please.

The code is working fine on my localhost. However, while deploying my code to Vercel, Vercel shows the following error.

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
FetchError: invalid json response body at (https://MY_BASE_URL)/api/getSkills reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:51220
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async fetchSkills (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1001:18)
    at async getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:929:20)
    at async renderToHTML (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:386:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:304:36
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
```

As far as I'm concerned, the issue originates from my fetch function(**FetchError**). My fetch function is as follows.

```
import {Project} from "../typing";

export const fetchProjects = async()=>{
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.MY_BASE_URL}/api/getProjects`);

  const data = await res.json();
  const projects: Project[] = data.projects;

  return projects;
}
```

If I run my code locally (MY_BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000), no FetchError occurs. However, if I pushed onto Vercel with Environment Variable Input (MY_BASE_URL = http://something-my-url.vercel.app), it shows the above error and stops.

I have done the followings but still cannot fix it.

1. Deploy it without fetching function (It worked).
2. Deploy it with fetching function using my domain generated through 1 (Not working).
3. Deploy it with fetching function using other two domains generated through 1 (Not working).

Thanks for reading it. Kindly help me solve the issue.

Comment: The base URL in production should be `https`: `https://something-my-url.vercel.app`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saved the environment variable as `{NAME: MY_BASE_URL, VALUE: https: https://xxxxxxxx.vercel.app}` but not working and showed the following error... `Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:553:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:629:5)
    at parseURL (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:61348)...........`

Comment: Finally, it worked. I have escaped from using MY_BASE_URL as suggested from the following references `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546341/how-to-handle-fetch-urls-with-nextjs` and `https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/blog-next-sanity`.